# Unexpected results when performing joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I've got a query more or less like the following:

```
select node from NODES node 
inner join SIGNATURES signature on node.NODE_ID=signature.NODE_ID and (... some non-important, AND separated restrictions on signature fields) 
left outer join OTHERS other on signature.ID=other.SIGNATURE_ID 
where node.DISABLED=0 and (some non-important, AND separated restrictions on node fields);
```

NODES has a 1..n relationship with SIGNATURES, and SIGNATURES has a 1..n relationship with OTHERS

The thing is, I've been told in some strange as of yet unidentified corner cases, this query returns, in production, a result containing nodes that have the DISABLED field set to 1. How is that possible?

Comment: plz do post the complete query! and also Required OUTPUT & Current OUTPUT few results!

Comment: The way you have written the query, it is not possible.

Comment: As we don't see the complete query: Make sure not to have forgotten parentheses with a mix of ANDs and ORs as in `where node.DISABLED=0 AND blabla OR thisnthat AND somestuff`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I hadn't fully checkhed the AND elements (since they are included from external source files), one of them included an OR and no parenthesis... If you post a response with that, I'll accept it.

Comment: I've done that. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not showing the complete query. It is possible that the WHERE clause contains a mix of ANDs and ORs and you have simply forgotten appropriate parentheses.

Example: `where node.DISABLED=0 AND blabla OR thisnthat AND somestuff`

Comment: Indeed, the problem was improper parenthisation on one of the AND subclauses, which contained an OR with a true value. I assumed I didn't understand something correctly about joins and didn't check it thoroughly enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way that could happen is a dirty read. In a production environment somebody could change the DISABLED value of a record after the record was selected by your query. This behavior is controlled through the Isolation Level, for a quick overview see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms709374%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

or any of the many excellent interpretations by numerous bloggers.

Isolation level is usually set at the database level, but in T-SQL, at least, you can request it in a query using hints. See READCOMMITTED, REPEATABLEREAD, etc. in
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx

You might want to add what your isolation level is to your post, it could help refine further answers.

Comment: Thanks, Horse, I thought READ UNCOMMITTED inherently implied dirty reads, I'm impressed Oracle managed to separate them! Nice explanation at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-nov/o65asktom-082389.html